# Метод двух указателей

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть [задача](http://codeforces.com/contest/616/problem/D) с codeforces. 
Там же есть [разбор](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22712).
Написал код по разбору, но почему-то неправильно работает на некоторых тестах(в комментариях в коде указано). 
З.Ы Если в коде что-то непонятно, то скажите, я прокомментирую.

**UPD** Улучшил код, чтобы удобнее было разобраться. Погонял отладчиком на тесте

10 2

2 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 2 1

Происходят странные вещи. Когда left переходит с третьего элемента на четвертый, то почему-то не удаляется из множества третий элемент и выходит left = right = 4, set_size = 2, хотя такого не может быть, вроде ж все правильно в коде.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector <size_t> cnt(1000001, 0);
size_t set_size = 0;

void set_add(const size_t& value){//Добавление элемента в множество
    cnt[value]++;
    if (cnt[value] == 1) set_size++;
    //cout << "set add " << value << "; set_size = " << set_size << endl;
}

void set_delete(const size_t& value){//Удаление элемента из множества
    if (!cnt[value] || !set_size) return;
   --cnt[value]; if (cnt[value] == 0) set_size--;
    //cout << "set del " << value << "; set_size = " << set_size << endl;
}

int main(){
    size_t n, k, ans = 0, ansl, ansr;
    //cin >> n >> k;
    n = 10; k = 2;
    vector <size_t> a = {2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1};//(n);
    //for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];
    size_t right = 0;
    for (size_t left = 0; left < n; left++){
        if (left > size_t(0)) set_delete(a[left - 1]);
        while (1){
            set_add(a[right]);
            if (set_size > k){
                set_delete(a[right]);
                right--;
                break;
            }
            if (right == n - 1) break;
            right++;
        }
        if (right - left + 1 > ans){
            ans = right - left + 1;
            ansl = left; ansr = right;
        }
    }
    cout << ansl + 1 << " "<< ansr + 1;
}
/*
WA1
10 2
2 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 2 1
Правильный ответ 5 10, а выводит 6 4
```

Comment: Ну, а почему вы не запустите код в отладчике и не посмотрите, что идёт не так, как ожидается?

Comment: Хм.. А мне захотелось дерево отрезков использовать, когда условие прочитал...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сказал что опечатка :)
Строка `set_add(a[right]);` вызывается сразу же после увелечения левой границы, при этом правая была посчитана ранее. 
Напишите её, например,  после `right++;`.

Comment: Теперь работает. Единственное что пришлось перед циклом добавить set_add(a[0]) иначе мы бы не добавляли первый элемент в множество. Прошло все тесты на CodeForces, спасибо. :)